# Missing component error Joomla in componenthelp.php

Tags: php, joomla

here are the errors:

```
Joomla\CMS\Component\Exception\MissingComponentException: Uncaught exception 'Joomla\CMS\Component\Exception\MissingComponentException' with message 'Component not found.' in /srv/www/httpdocs/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:346
```

here are the stack trace :

```
…rv/www/httpdocs/libraries/src/Application/
SiteApplication.php (194)
…rv/www/httpdocs/libraries/src/Application/
SiteApplication.php (233)
…srv/www/httpdocs/libraries/src/Application/
CMSApplication.php (267)
…CMSApplication::execute called at /srv/www/httpdocs/
index.php (49)
```

what are the possible reasons for the errors ? How can i ensure that joomla doesnt throw this error ?

Comment: it's really too general as a question... give some context ! version of joomla, custom components or not, etc...

Comment: joomla version is 3.8.3 , and error details  is not pointing to any custom modules

Comment: enable debug and set maximum error reporting. try to disable all 3rd party modules and plugins